# Can’t connect nodes with shade editor any fix?

Tags: node-editor

I try to connect with using nodes with shade editor but it doesn’t work.[image]

Comment: Latest drivers installed? Might be a bug: https://developer.blender.org/T74355 BTW: Blender comes with a built-in screenshot tool: *Window > Save Screenshot*...

Comment: Hi. https://www.take-a-screenshot.org/ should help with taking clearer screenshots in future. The current ones are quite hard to see. Thanks.